# How to make the date format of a Lightpick calendar respond to window size

Tags: javascript

I'm adding a pre-built JS calendar to a dashboard ([Lightpick](https://wakirin.github.io/Lightpick/)) and want to make the date format change depending on the size of the window. So, for example, when the user reduces the size < 1000 pixels, the format changes from 'DD MMM YYYY' to 'DD/MM/YY'. Problem is - my solution only updates the format on load!

Lightpick sets the format to 'DD/MM/YYYY' by default. I have tried creating a variable called myDynamicFormat and updating that on screen resize - but no luck. It seems the code runs once on page load and doesn't update again, unless refreshed. Here's the resize function I created trying to update the format when the width is below/over 1000 pixels :

```
window.onresize = function() {
  if (screen.width < 1000) {
    myDynamicFormat = 'DD/MM/YY';
  } else {
    myDynamicFormat = 'DD MMM YYYY';
  }
};
```

And here is the format part in the picker variable created, as per the Lickpick documentation:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="lightpick-master/lightpick.js"></script>

var picker = new Lightpick({
  format: myDynamicFormat,
...etc...
});
```

I have also tried setting it to the innerHTML and value of DIVs hidden in the HTML with no luck, either. Also tried using an operator command like "picker.format = ..." to reassign the value.

I'd like that myDynamicFormat field in the picker variable to listen to the variable after page load - able to update with the page.

Thank you for your help with this - I am new to JS and this is proving to be a learning experience!

Comment: Changing that variable won't affect the value that was used when you initialized Lightpick. Perhaps that script has ability to change options programmatically after initialization?

Comment: A few things: window.onresize is not a good practice — window.addEventListener('resize', () => {}) is less fragile. This might be simpler to accomplish using responsive CSS, but in any event it's really the size of the element itself and not the screen or window that should drive the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work for you.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var getWidth = $(window).width();
    if (getWidth < 1000) {
        myDynamicFormat = 'DD/MM/YY';
    } else {
        myDynamicFormat = 'DD MMM YYYY';
    };
};
```